# Solr collection with lots of dynamic fields

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We are planning to use solr cloud with single collection for our multi tenant product.

The collection schema is setup with lot of dynamic fields and essentially each client would have their own set of fields.

Is there any limitations on number of fields a solr collection can handle?

Comment: There is no general limitation, but be aware that caches/etc. usually are _per field_, so you'll end up with a lot of un-used caches. It might be a better idea to scale your application by having a separate collection for each tenant instead, if their datasets are _that_ different.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh. Did think about collection per tenant. But saw a comment in solr documentation (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SOLR/SolrPerformanceProblems#SolrPerformanceProblems-SolrCloud) about using too many collections could have an impact on solr cloud stability.

Comment: That's a rather outdated document / configuration, where the state of the cluster was kept in a single file. These days the state is kept per collection instead of globally, which makes it far more efficient. However, having multiple solrcloud clusters will be easier to scale horizontally than trying to keep everything in a single instance.

Comment: Given that you already have your tenants and their data, I'd just start there and benchmark whether it suits your needs - and then start trickling in traffic to see if performance is what you need or if you'll need to scale out more.